# Let Jenkins edit file retrieved from Git before executing the project

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests

In my Maven project, I need to set parameters before execution, in two different types of files: Java classes and other files, whose extension is ".ta".
I'm able to edit the Java classes by setting Jenkins' goals and options. For example:

The goal I set in Jenkins:

```
-Denv.baseurl="www.wonderful-website.woah"
```

What I have in my Java class:

```
public String baseUrl = System.getProperty("env.baseurl");
```

But I cannot do the same with the .ta files. (Just for your info, they are from a software called Squash TA, where TA means "test automation"). I cannot edit them from a Java class because they are executed before any Java class. The only solution seems to edit then before the beginning of the execution. For this purpose, I added a pre-build step in my job's configuration, where I launch a shell script. I looks like this:

```
sed 's/placeholder/value-i-need/g' ./path-to-my-file # This path is relative to Jenkins' workspace
```

When I check the console during the build, I notice the replacement is going great:

```
23:04:45 + sed 's/placeholder/value-i-need/g' ./path-to-my-file
23:04:45 Here I am, value-i-need
```

But it's just a false hope :D since later on, the script is retrieved from Git, and is built as is.
So I wonder: is there any way to edit a file within the Jenkins workspace after they are retrieved from Git and before the execution of the project?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How you get your sources from Git? If you are defined your Git in " 
Source Code Management", Jenkins clones your repository BEFORE it executes "Pre-Build" steps. So, check you shell script, maybe it's not correct. It may be not correct "sed" command. Try this: sed -e 's/placeholder/value-i-need/g' -i '' ./path-to-my-file

Comment: You're right! The "-i" argument was missing. I can't explain why the replacement was echoed before but wasn't applied to the actual code. Anyway, thanks a lot.